# NavigationPage Title Not Changing in .NET8 MAUI App

Tags: navigation, maui, .net-7.0, hamburger-menu, .net-8.0

NavigationPage Title is not changing in Windows and Android platforms when we navigate from one activity to another activity through hamburger menu and title is not changing when switching between pages also in MAUI application targeting .NET8.

But, it works fine in .NET7 in all platforms.

```
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyoutPageSample"
        x:Class="FlyoutPageSample.AppFlyout"
        FlyoutLayoutBehavior="Popover"
        >
<FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <local:FlyoutMenuPage x:Name="flyoutPage" />
</FlyoutPage.Flyout>
<FlyoutPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MainPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</FlyoutPage.Detail>
```

```
flyoutPage.collectionView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;

void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FlyoutPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            //IsPresented = false;
        }
}

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyoutPageSample"
             x:Class="FlyoutPageSample.FlyoutMenuPage"
             Title="FlyoutMenuPage">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Contacts"
                                      IconSource="contacts.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="TodoList"
                                      IconSource="todo.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage2}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Reminders"
                                      IconSource="reminders.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage3}" />
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="5,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="20,0"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show what it currently looks like. Since this could be a bug in MAUI, have you checked the [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) in the official GitHub repo?

Comment: @Julian Thanks for your response. Above mentioned is the sample code which replicates the issue. Yes, we have looked into Github issues and found that it is an issue in .NET8.

Comment: @Saravana Which Github issue? Can you add it to your post? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18830

Comment: @Saravana Thanks for the update, confirmed that it works as expected with the 8.0.0-nightly.9637 nightly build. You may need wait for 8.0.4 release. And here's an sample for your reference:https://github.com/MartyIX/MauiNightlySample/blob/9ef12cc409faf238ee32daad19ea4340e180fc22/MauiNightlySample.csproj#L43C16-L43C34

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, Sure, will check in next MAUI release.

Comment: @Saravana Thanks for the response, please provide an update if it works in the next release.